# I am trying to display emojis based on minutes it takes to read the specific article

Tags: reactjs, loops, if-statement, emoji

If the article takes less than 30 minutes to read:

For every 5 minutes (rounded up to the nearest 5), display a coffee cup emoji. For example, if the article takes 3 minutes to read, you should display "☕️ 3 min read". If the article takes 7 minute, you should display "☕️☕️ 7 min read".

If the article takes 30 minutes or longer to read:

For every 10 minutes (rounded up to the nearest 10), display a bento box emoji. For example, if the article takes 35 minutes to read, you should display " 35 min read". If the article takes 61 minutes to read, you should display " 61 min read".

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
import React from "react";

function Article({ title, date = "January 1, 1970", preview, minutes }) {
  function roundNearest5(num) {
    return Math.round(num / 5);
  }
  function roundNearest10(num) {
    return Math.round(num / 10);
  }

  const emoji = function displayEmoji() {
    if (minutes <= 30) {
      for (let i = 0; i <= roundNearest5(minutes); i++) {
        return("☕️");
      }
    } else {
      for (let i = 0; i <= roundNearest10(minutes); i++) {
        return ("");
      }
    }
  }


  return (
    <article>
      <h3>{title}</h3>
      <small>{date}</small>
      <span>{emoji}</span>
      <p>{preview}</p>
    </article>
  );
}

export default Article;
```

How do I get to display the correct number of emojis given an array of minutes for each article as [5, 15, 47]

Comment: `return` inside of the `for` loop will just return 1 emoji "character", only 1 loop iteration will be executed, you need to build a string to return in your for loops and return it outside of them.

Comment: You've explained what you're trying to do, and you've posted some code, which is good. However, you've forgotten to explain the problem you're having with your code, and you have not asked a question at all, which is not so good. Can you [edit] your post to add that information, so that we can try to help?

Comment: @KenWhite sorry about that, edited the question hope its better now.

Comment: @SergeySosunov thanks for your guidance was able to resolve the issue
`function displayEmoji() {
    const emojiArray = [];
    if (minutes <= 30) {
      for (let i = 0; i < roundNearest5(minutes); i++) {
        emojiArray.push("☕️");
      }
     return(emojiArray.join(' ') + ' ' + minutes + " mins to read");
    } else {
      for (let i = 0; i < roundNearest10(minutes); i++) {
        emojiArray.push("");
      }
      return emojiArray.join('') + " " + minutes + " mins to read";
    }
  }
`